# Fullcalendar JSON events - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 't.start.hasTime')

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I have a Problem that i don't understand. I am getting my events from my App by calling my api and i get a json-answer that looks like this:

```
{
"events": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Event 1",
        "start": "2016-11-02T08:30:00",
        "end": "2016-11-02T10:00:00"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "EVENT 2",
        "start": "2016-11-01T08:30:00",
        "end": "2016-11-01T10:00:00"
    }
]}
```

if i paste this output directly in my javascript fullcalendar everything works fine, but if i fetch it with ajax i'm getting this t.start.hasTime() error.

somehow it looks like it doesn't find my start attribute, but it is there.
I'm calling the events with this code.

```
events: [
        // your event source
        {
            url: '/api/schedule/', // use the `url` property
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    ]
```

Comment: even with this answer  it doesn't work:
    [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "Event 1",
        "start": "2016-11-02T08:30:00",
        "end": "2016-11-02T10:00:00"
    }]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself...

it works if i call my api just like this ... sometimes it is too easy :)

```
events:  '/api/schedule/'
```

and not with the array of events... maybe it has to be eventSource instead... anyways it works now.

Comment: an it has to be a flat json object